# Xcode crash caused by sqlite3_bind_text function in objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

I am trying to take text that the user inputs in a text view section (outlet named `viewNotes`) and put it into a DB after clicking a submit button. When I run the app it works fine until I hit submit and then I get a crash (breakpoint) on the `sqlite3_bind_text` function. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is the action code:

```
- (IBAction)submitNotes:(id)sender {
NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"highpeaks.db"];

sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *theNewStmt;
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "UPDATE Peaks SET notes=? WHERE ID=?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &theNewStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
NSLog(@"%@",self.viewNotes.text);
sqlite3_bind_text(theNewStmt, 1, [self.viewNotes.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(theNewStmt, 2, [self.detailItem ID]);

char* errmsg;
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(theNewStmt))
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
sqlite3_finalize(theNewStmt);

sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: Either you have set breakpoint or it crashed on that point.

Comment: It crashed. I just edited my post to make that more clear.

Comment: Im 99% sure the error is that theNewStmt isn't being assigned correctly, are you sure you're using the right data type?

Comment: I don't know how to find the log. Can you instruct me how? Thanks!

Comment: @user1458968, I used practically this same exact code in another function to save an integer in the DB and it works fine. So I'm not sure if it's the statement assignment, because it worked fine in the other function.

Comment: to log do `NSLog(@"%@",thingyToLog);`, changing the %@ to match whatever data type you are trying to present

Comment: @user1458968, when I comment out the `NSLog` part of the code it still crashes. I just used that to make sure there was at least something in the text field.

Comment: Oh my mistake I didn't see that, I was responding to your how to fid the log comment.

Comment: @user1458968, no problem, I just don't know how to find the crash logs. Maybe it would help me debug my own code better!!

Comment: Run your project through instruments, command+I will do it, or do Product -> Profile in xcode. if it is grayed out, go to Product -> Edit Scheme and make sure Build Config is set to Debug and your executable is right. Instruments will let you see lots of info on everything thats happening, google it to find someone more knowledgable than me to explain it all haha

Comment: Just a note - storing unsanitized text into a DB without validation is just asking for an SQL injection attack, or cross-site scripting (XSS), depending on how the data is used by the application.  You should read up on both those topics and make sure your application sanitizes the text before storing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what was wrong with the above code, but this code works just fine:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3 *cruddb;

//insert
const char *sql = "UPDATE Peaks SET notes=? where ID=?";

//Open db
NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cruddatabase = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"highpeaks.db"];

sqlite3_open([cruddatabase UTF8String], &cruddb);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [self.viewNotes.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, [self.detailItem ID]);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(cruddb);
```